# error 1054 (42s22) in on clause Players.fname column unknown

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT *
FROM `Players` p
INNER JOIN `Teams` t1
ON  (t1.Team_id = Players.fname)
INNER JOIN `Teams` t2
ON  (t2.Team_id = Players.fname)
WHERE ( t1.league = 'AL' AND t1.div = 'West' )
AND ( t2.league = 'AL' AND t2.div = 'East' );
```

I'm not sure why it is an unknown column as I know for a fact I have a fname column.

I would appreciate the help!

Comment: Why would you be joining on `team_id` and `fname`?  Please post your table schema, sample data and desired results.

Comment: ok first of all I meant to put `lname` but that's hardly the point.  I want to join those two tables, I think, because I want to display last name and what team they play for.                                                                sample data                                                   `('Goldschmidt','Paul','1987-9-10',DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 year),29),
('Keuchel','Dallas','1988-1-1',DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 4 year,13),
Team info                                                                                       `('Free Agent','',''),
('Blue Jays','AL','East'),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You alias the players table, but then refer to it with its original name. Either do not alias the table or use the alias throughout the whole sql statement.

Comment: huh? ok that cleared the error but now it says its an empty set I know all those field have data in them. Am I just now asking a clear question of my database?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot possibly say why a particular sql statement does not return results on data completely unknown to me. I provided answer to what you have asked.

Comment: That you did and I love you for that @Shadow

Comment: Are you sure that team id would be the same as a part of a name?

Comment: It wouldn't team_id is the primary key which I thought would be able translate to the name. The column that has the name is `team name`